# obj-c array handling - How to add first object?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am struggling with a noob thing. I have this loop through an initialized array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {

       [array addSomeObject...];
    }
```

How do I add the first object? The loop is not executed as array.count is 0. I probably deserve to be voted down for this. Just tell me how to deal with it :! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the array's count to do this. If you have a count that you want the array to have when your finished, use that number in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Decide how many items you want in the array and use that number as the loop limit - not the count as it is obviously zero. Note that if you create an array with a capacity but don't add anything to it it still has a count of zero. The capacity is just a hint at how much memory should be allocated for the array.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. At least I understand. I think though, that my design is flawed, that I have this circumstance, so I'm rethinking this piece. (volatile join tables and multiple selections). I got stuck, and you both helped me get unstuck, so thank you.